Super slow installation of libmamba solver on conda
Very interesting design that drives me crazy. I'm installing libmamba solver for anaconda because I can't install any libraries on conda now. Every conda installation takes forever. However, even installing libmamba seems not possible.
I'm using conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
This installation literally have been running for 2 days. More than 48 hours. And still examining conflicts on some packages. Is there any solution on this? I don't really want to uninstall the whole thing and start over again as there were some libraries in the base environment needed to be mannually installed and had took me a long time...
I've tried update conda. Also stucked at solving environments.

You probably have a bloated base environment.  The solver is struggling to resolve all of the dependencies.  You can try to install the libmamba solver and its dependencies manually without resolving the environment.
conda install conda-libmamba-solver libmambapy boltons libmamba -y -c anaconda --override-channels --no-deps

Your better option is to create new environments that you can install just what is needed into, rather than having the 140+ packages in Anaconda plus all of your new stuff as well to resolve.
